# Making UIActivityIndicator be the same size as the on in UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview, uirefreshcontrol

I am trying to make a UIActivityIndicator be the same size as the on in UIRefreshControl since sometimes I need to refresh the screen manually and sometimes the data is refreshed without pulling the screen, so I need to simulate the activity indicator.

```
 _refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    _refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [_refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshItems) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.collectionView addSubview:_refreshControl];


    UIView *activityIndicatorWrapper = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_refreshControl.frame];

    [self.collectionView addSubview:activityIndicatorWrapper];

    _activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityIndicatorWrapper.frame = _refreshControl.bounds;

    [activityIndicatorWrapper addSubview:_activityIndicator];
    [_activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [_activityIndicator autoCenterInSuperview];
    _activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
```

Problem is that the sizes are different, even though I make them the same frame..

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do this as well. I don't think it is possible especially as we can't see what UIKit is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: how did you solve it? so far I skip the manual refresh, because its more of a hassle

Answer (score 0):

Change `y: -105` to what you want, maybe try `y: 0` first

Run this then try pulling to refresh, hope this helps

```
    private func setupTableViewRefresher() {
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

        refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: " ", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear, NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 56)])
        refreshControl.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.6, y: 0.6)
        refreshControl.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor
        
        // refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshTableView(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        
        tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    }

    private func createSpinnerFooter() -> UIView {
        let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -105, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 100))

        let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        spinner.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
        spinner.center = footerView.center
        footerView.addSubview(spinner)
        spinner.startAnimating()
        
        return footerView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                
        setupTableViewRefresher()

        tableView.isHidden = false
        tableView.tableFooterView = nil

        tableView.tableFooterView = self.createSpinnerFooter()
    }
```